# How to covert LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>to int[][] type using stream in Java 8?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

How can I convert a `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>` to `int[][]` type?

I have created

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

I want to convert the result to `int[][]` type using Java 8 functionality.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the problem you've encountered?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, how would one convert a `LinkedList<Integer>` to an `int[]` using Streams?

This is done by streaming the values, converting the `Stream<Integer>` to an `IntStream`, and using its built-in `toArray()` method:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = something;
int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()
```

Now that we can convert the inner list, what do we do about the outer list? We start by streaming it (as a `Stream<LinkedList<Integer>>`), converting the inner data using the above approach (thus making a `Stream<int[]>`), and then outputting that as an array:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> list = something;
int[][] array = list.stream()
    .map(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray())
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```